# JavaScript add Onclick Event

Tags: javascript, html

How can i add a onclick event to a certain td cell of a table ?

I have a form in which i have a field where i want to display something on click:

```
<input type="text" name="tip">
```

This is the function i am using :

```
function setText(day, hour){
    var tipField = document.getElementsByName('tip');
    tipField.value = day + "  " + hour;
}
```

And here i am trying to add onClick event to td's(those ids are td's ids):

```
el[0] = document.getElementById('j1');
el[1] = document.getElementById('j2');
el[2] = document.getElementById('j3');
el[3] = document.getElementById('j4');
el[4] = document.getElementById('j5');
```

First method:

```
el[1].onclick="setText('Monday', '10:00')";
```

Second method:

```
el.addEventListener("click", function(){
                setText('Joi','09:00');
            });
```

But none seems to work.

Comment: `el[1].addEventListener(...`

Comment: I've done this and when the page loads it automatically sets the text without clicking

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AddEventListener("EVENT",FUNCTION_NAME)` for dynamically add listener.
Here we add CLICK for all `<tr>` of table

```js
var table = document.getElementById("our_table");
console.log(table);
function DOIT(){
  console.log("TR Clicked");
  }
for(i=0;i<=table.childElementCount;i++){
  table.rows[i].addEventListener("click",DOIT);
  }
```

```html
<table id="our_table">
  <tr><td>Name</td><td>Family</td>
    </tr>
  <tr><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

open console for see result.